# "\" not considered as char in string char

Tags: shell

I am still having issue with my fastq script. This time I have an issue with how the script handle input.

this is part of my script

```
while read Sequence_Name && read Sequence && read Quality_name && read Quality_sequence
n=1
do

            if [[ ${#Sequence} != ${#Quality_sequence} ]] ; then
                echo "Length of Sequence $n different from Length of Quality Sequence"
                echo ${#Sequence} #line added to see the ouput
                echo $Sequence #line added to see the ouput 
                echo ${#Quality_sequence} #line added to see the ouput
                echo $Quality_sequence #line added to see the ouput
             fi
n=$((n+1))
done <$1
```

the issue is that the ouput does not look like the input. such as

this is what is in the input file :

```
@SRR1350630.196.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:7018:1029 length=24
TGTAAACATCCTACACTCTCAGCT
+SRR1350630.196.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:7018:1029 length=24
`__^\\aa_Z_ccccacc[a\cYc
@SRR1350630.197.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:8338:1032 length=24
TTTGGCAATGGTAGAACTCACACC
+SRR1350630.197.1 HWUSI-EAS753_0012:8:1:8338:1032 length=24
acaa^acc^ac[aacY^\`_cccc
```

but this is what the output gave me

```
Length of Sequence 196 different from Length of Quality Sequence

24 # this is the echo ${#sequence}
TGTAAACATCCTACACTCTCAGCT # this is the echo $Sequence
22 # this is the echo ${#Quality_sequence}
`__^\aa_Z_ccccacc[acYc #this is the echo $Quality_sequence

Length of Sequence 197 different from Length of Quality Sequence
24
TTTGGCAATGGTAGAACTCACACC
23
acaa^acc^ac[aacY^`_cccc
```

You may have noticed that the script remove all \ from the input except \\ that it is considered as one \. So inducing a shift in the lenght of the quality_sequence.

thanks for your help again

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `-r` argument to `read`. You basically **always** want it. It prevents `read` from "interpreting" backslash escape sequences.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for discussion about how to properly read files by line/field correctly (which discusses `-r`).